# Is there a way to close the shell of the container after installing package?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I try to automate the configuration of raspios through bash script. My configurations are on network level and for that I need to install a package named vlan, so my try ist to use systemd-nspwan on mounted image.

My Problem is, when I start the container, a new shell is opened.

I need to install the package and after that close the container / shell to return to the root.

```
systemd-nspawn -D /mnt
if dpkg -l | grep vlan; then
    exit 1
else
    apt install vlan
fi
```

How can I exit the subshell so I can get back to root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the mans page of systemd-nspawn I found out that you can pass the command without opening an interactive shell by simply adding your wished command as an parameter of systemd-nspwan.

```
systemd-nspawn <wished command>
```